# How to reset page number to 1 in python-docx?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I've added a Field 'Page' to my code using code:

```
def _add_field(run, field):
    """ add a field to a run
    """
    fldChar1 = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')  # creates a new element
    fldChar1.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'begin')  # sets attribute on element
    instrText = OxmlElement('w:instrText')
    instrText.set(qn('xml:space'), 'preserve')  # sets attribute on element
    instrText.text = field

    fldChar2 = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
    fldChar2.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'separate')
    t = OxmlElement('w:t')
    t.text = "Right-click to update field."
    fldChar2.append(t)

    fldChar4 = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
    fldChar4.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'end')

    r_element = run._r
    r_element.append(fldChar1)
    r_element.append(instrText)
    r_element.append(fldChar2)
    r_element.append(fldChar4)

def _add_number_range(run, name):
    """ add a number range field to a run
    """
    _add_field(run, r'SEQ %s \* ARABIC' % name)
```

Now as section is on page-3 of the document its getting number 3 and further pages get the page number as 4,5,...

How to reset this starting page number for that section as 1 from 3 using python-docx?

Here is the image of doing it from MSWord:
[Solution from MSWord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22S3i.png)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the programming language, but I think I can help you find the answer, as your code appears to mirror the Word Open XML fairly closely. The page number information is stored in the section break *following* the section content. The XML for a section break with renumbering set to 1 (look for `w:pgNumType `): `<w:sectPr ><w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/><w:pgMar w:top="1417" w:right="1417" w:bottom="1134" w:left="1417" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/><w:pgNumType w:start="1"/><w:cols w:space="708"/><w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/></w:sectPr>`

Comment: So it would be a matter of appending/inserting the w:pgNumType element. Note that the *order* of elements is often important in the Word Open XML Schema.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph

def create_page_number_type(start_num: int=1):  # type: ignore
    num_type = OxmlElement('w:pgNumType')
    num_type.set(qn('w:start'), str(start_num))
    return num_type

def make_page_number(p: Paragraph) -> None:
    run = p.add_run()
    fldChar1 = OxmlElement("w:fldChar")
    fldChar1.set(qn("w:fldCharType"), "begin")

    instrText = OxmlElement("w:instrText")
    instrText.set(qn("xml:space"), "preserve")
    instrText.text = "PAGE"

    fldChar2 = OxmlElement("w:fldChar")
    fldChar2.set(qn("w:fldCharType"), "end")

    r_element = run._r  # noqa: protected-access
    r_element.append(fldChar1)
    r_element.append(instrText)
    r_element.append(fldChar2)
    p.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER


content_section: Section = document.sections[-1]
pg_num_type = create_page_number_type(start_num=1)
content_section._sectPr.append(pg_num_type) # noqa: protected-access

content_section_footer = content_section.footer
content_section_footer.is_linked_to_previous = False
make_page_number(content_section_footer.paragraphs[0])
```